# How to render a double bottom border on a single table cell?

Tags: tables, rules

How to render a double bottom border on a single table cell? In the example table,

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}
\hline
Item  & Sales & Total \\ \hline
Item 1 & 10 &  \\ \hline
Item 1 & 10 & 20 \\ \hline
Item 1 & 10 &  \\ \hline
Item 2 & 10 &  \\ \hline
Item 2 & 10 & 30 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to place a double border under the cells containing 20 and 30 to delimit a group sub total?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically one could use [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) to modify the horizontal rule within a `tabular`, allowing a mixture of single and double lines. However, the output in your case is not very desirable. Here's an alternative, showing a modified version of your input (using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)) first *with* `\hhline` and then *without* (and some other tricks):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{booktabs,hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
  Item  & Sales & Total \\
  \midrule
  Item 1 & 10 &    \\
  Item 1 & 10 & 20 \\ \hhline{--=}
  Item 1 & 10 &    \\
  Item 2 & 10 &    \\
  Item 2 & 10 & 30 \\ \hhline{--=}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
  Item  & Sales & Total \\
  \midrule
  Item 1 & 10 &    \\
  Item 1 & 10 & 20 \\ \hline \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\arrayrulewidth+1pt]
    \cline{3-3}
  Item 1 & 10 &    \\
  Item 2 & 10 &    \\
  Item 2 & 10 & 30 \\ \hline \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\arrayrulewidth+1pt]
    \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The second option inserts a regular `\hline` followed by a `1pt` gap and `\cline{3-3}` (modify `1pt` for a different gap). More specifically, `\dimexpr` allows for an expression of dimensions, jumping back (vertically upward) a full baseline skip (`-\normalbaselineskip`) and then forward (vertically downward) the default width of the rule (`\arrayrulewidth`, typically `0.4pt`) plus `1pt`.

I'm sure another technique would also suffice; this just seemed the most straight forward. This is mainly based on style, so there are other options as well.

The later option needs some additional hacking when using vertical borders also,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}
  Item  & Sales & Total \\
  Item 1 & 10 &    \\
  Item 1 & 10 & 20 \\ \hline 
  & & \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\arrayrulewidth+1pt] \cline{3-3}
  Item 1 & 10 &    \\
  Item 2 & 10 &    \\
  Item 2 & 10 & 30 \\ \hline 
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} 
  \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\arrayrulewidth+1pt] \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second option, works great in long table environment also. @werner you might just want to explain what `\\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\arrayrulewidth+1pt]` does?

Comment: @entropy Here, `\normalbaselineskip` is the height of the textline you add by ``\\``. Using `\dimexpr` we calculate a good negative height to input to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

`hhline` is designed to make such partial lines easy to produce:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}
\hline
Item  & Sales & Total \\ \hline
Item 1 & 10 &  \\ \hline
Item 1 & 10 & 20 \\ \hhline{|-|-|=|}
Item 1 & 10 &  \\ \hline
Item 2 & 10 &  \\ \hline
Item 2 & 10 & 30 \\ \hhline{|-|-|=|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```